# AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

```
from serial import serial
joystick = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
joystick_x = joystick.write('0')
if joystick_x==1023:
    print("Right")
elif joystick_x != 1023:
    print("Not right");
```

and I received error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mine_science/Desktop/snu6/산출물/arduino.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import serial
  File "C:\Users\Mine_science\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serial\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from serial.serialutil import *
ImportError: No module named 'serial.serialutil'
```

also Can you give me some advices to get each pin.

Comment: do you have a file in your app called serial.py?

Comment: The error message in the heading doesn't match the one in the body. Which one are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like you only need to do

`import serial`

instead of

`from serial import serial`

http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html

Comment: I solved problem. Actually, I didn't download the library inside the Python:P

Comment: After installing the serial library using pip3, I get the same answer even though I'm using Import serial to call it.

Answer (score 29):

I installed serial library using "pip3 install serial" and get the same error even calling the library using "import serial". Then I found that if first UNINSTALL serial:

```
pip3 uninstall serial
```

and then install pyserial:

```
pip3 install pyserial
```

fixed the problem for python 3.

Comment: This solved my `AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'`.

Comment: In my case reinstalling pyserial helped.

Answer (score 2):

uninstalling python and pyserial package completely and then

installing python(python 3 in my case) back -

> for all users and add Paths correctly

and then use

> pip3  for installing pyserial

fixed all my issues

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, but what works for me was:

1. uninstall serial  : `pip3 uninstall serial`
2. uninstall pyserial: `pip3 uninstall pyserial`
3. reinstall a previous version of pyserial: `pip3 install pyserial==3.3`
   (I had 3.5 version)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use minimalmodbus and got the same error message as in the title of this post. What worked for me:

`sudo apt install python-is-python3`

Apparently there was some confusion between python 2 and 3 and python-is-python3 resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the below worked when I encountered this same problem:

```
from serial import *
```