# Can't get .exe to execute on other machine - "No module named serial" error

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, pyserial

**System:** Python 3.7 64x running on Windows 10. I also have Anaconda installed on my machine and I program through VS Code. All modules have been installed, verified installed, and are up-to-date.

I have written a script and compiled it into an .exe using pyinstaller. `pyinstaller -wFi pyico.ico endpointapp3.py`.The .exe works and runs on my machine but it's not meant for my computer. Previous iterations of this script have been compiled, tested, and worked appropriately on its destination computer, a Windows 7 machine with no python installed.

My latest version now includes pyserial, and works, again, on my machine, but I after compiling and creating an .exe file for the destination machine I encounter this error.

```
File "endpointapp2.py", line 9 in <module> 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial' 
[3512] Failed to execute script endpointapp2.py
```

Line 9 is my `import serial` line

As I mentioned before, this executable runs on my machine, but not on the destination machine it was designed for. I don't want to install python, or python modules on the destination machine because I want the .exe to be all inclusive.

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting this error? What does it mean?
2. Is there a work around that allows me to compile everything together (using pyinstaller) that will hold all the necessary module
       information within the .exe?
3. Is there something else I should be adding to my original script that will allow me to work through this?

---

[*NOT A DUPLICATE*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267070/no-module-named-serial) - This post is for compiling and running python .exe's on another machine, independent of python, with no modules or python installed.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and describe/show how you built the .exe with pyinstaller.

Comment: @martineau Done

Comment: That's a line in your .py file, _not_ a description of how you used pyinstaller to create the .exe that doesn't work.

Comment: @martineau That's *not* a line in my .py file. It's the line I type in Python to compile my .py script into an .exe. That's all I've done with pyinstaller. It's literally the only time I've typed pyinstaller or used the module.

Comment: OK, that's what I wanted to know. Apparently the default way pyinstaller builds .exe files from Python scripts isn't including the third-party `serial` module you're using. What exactly is that and where did you get it (or was it part of Anaconda)? Note: here's the pyinstaller [manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) so you can do the same.

Comment: @martineau I did a `pip install pyserial`. I'll look through the manual. Thank you. If you think of anything else please let me know.

Comment: Here's a [section](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs) of the pyinstaller manual that describes how it tries to determine what imports your script uses (and how to "help" it when it misses one). A related [page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) shows what modules it understands and the closest thing I can find is "PySerial" and it sounds like using it should work without doing anything extra—so the question becomes Why isn't pyinstaller working properly in this case?

Comment: @martineau Got it! Will you change your comment to an answer so I can accept it please! THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome...I think—what machine did you do the `pip install pyserial` on, because if it was the other machine (assuming it was already installed on your own) then pyinstaller didn't work correctly and doing the pip install of the missing module is just a workaround for the real problem.

Comment: @martineau By changing the .spec file I was able to make sure pyinstaller included the necessary module information in the .exe. I did not have to install python, or any modules on the destination machine. It's all included in the .exe.

Comment: In that case I think you should post an answer your own question (which is perfectly OK to do here)—all I did was point you in the right direction. `;¬)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267070/no-module-named-serial)

Comment: what exactly did you change in the spec file, can you please let me know. I am facing the same issue as well. Thanks

Comment: I just updated my pyinstaller and things worked normally as the other system, no issue of no module serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some assistance and helpful advice (thanks martineau) I was able to solve my problem. When compiling with pyinstaller, it makes a .spec file that it actually uses to compile to .exe.

[Here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs) I found the necessary steps to make sure I was adding the files I needed for pyinstaller.

[Here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module) I found out how to properly add the module information into my compiling code.

Once pyinstaller had the correct info in the .spec file I was able to compile and execute on the destination machine as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue when i move my code into serial module location.
First find where serial module locate :

```
>>> import serial
>>> serial.__file__
'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\serial\\__init__.py'
```

mine is above.

Then move your file into :

```
'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\{your_file.py}'
```

Then run pyinstaller :

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_file.py --additional-hooks-dir serial\\__init__.py
```

Run your .exe from dist folder. No longer showing error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is something wrong with PySerial 3.5
downgrading to 3.3 solved the issue.
I think @PyInstaller and @PySerial should duke it out.
cost me 4 hrs, until I saw [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509753/21384460)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509753/21384460

Comment: What is the gist of the link content (in case it is deleted)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509753/21384460

Answer (score -2):

The module is called `pyserial`, but the library call in the code is `import serial`. Pyinstaller is unable to complete the build because there truly is no module named `serial`.

To correct this you need to tell pyinstaller to import the correct package by including it in the .spec file under hiddenimports.

`hiddenimports=['pyserial']`

This will be true for any case where the package name and the import statement call are not the same.